# Trying to read checkin data from Foursquare using Python

Tags: python, json, foursquare

I am trying to retrieve all the (self) user checkins, however when I parse the JSON returned I cannot seem to get down to the individual checkin level, this is code I am testing with. Bit of a newbie with Python and JSON and struggling to understand what is wrong with this as it present if I add 'items' to the for loop it never even gets entered. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins/'
full_url = url + '?' + data

req = urllib2.Request(full_url)
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
f = opener.open(req)
fsdata = simplejson.load(f)

for item in fsdata['response']['checkins']['items']:
    print item
```

Sorry should've been clear. I have omitted the auth process for clarity. If I return fsdata to the page I see the top json levels:

Notifications
Meta
Response

Comment: In order for the response to mean anything you must identify yourself as a specific user, otherwise the JSON you get back defines an error state (which you have to handle if you want your code to be robust). Or at least this would explain why you see no items.

You can learn about authentication at https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth.html, though this will perhaps make your program a little more complex.

Comment: Along the lines of that first comment, it would help if you would add the JSON response to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was my formatting of epoch I was passing to the Foursquare API call was wrong (it was in milliseconds) so I never got any checkin detail, here is the corrected code:

```
access_token = request.session.get('access_token')

#calculate unix epoch minus one week
daynow=date.today()-timedelta(days=7)
#convert to epoch in seconds
epoch = int(time.mktime(daynow.timetuple()))

params = { 'oauth_token' : access_token, 'v' : today_yyyymmdd(), 'afterTimestamp' : epoch  }
data = urllib.urlencode( params )

#endpoint call for all user checkins
url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins/'
full_url = url + '?' + data

req = urllib2.urlopen(full_url)
fsdata=json.load(req)
fsout=[]
for item in fsdata['response']['checkins']['items']:
    fsout.append(item['id'])
    fsout.append(item['createdAt'])
    fsout.append(item['venue']['name'])
```